# How to get a Module object from a ModuleReference

Tags: java, java-9

Using the code:

```
ModuleFinder.of(Paths.get(path)).findAll()
```

I am able to retrieve a `Set<ModuleReference>` of all the ***.jars*** in the `path` folder.

My next step would be getting a `Module` from a [`ModuleReference`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleReference.html) but there's no method that returns that, I can get a [`ModuleDescriptor`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleDescriptor.html) but even that one doesn't help. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need this?

Answer (score 4):

If you desire to access the *module content* you should [`open`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleReference.html#open--) the `ModuleReference` that you've attained.
This would provide you access to the [`ModuleReader`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleReader.html) which

> is intended for cases where access to the  resources in a module is
>   required
>
> A resource in a module is identified by an abstract name that is a
>   `'/'`-separated path string. For example, module `java.base` 
>   may have a resource `"java/lang/Object.class"` that, by convention, 
>   is the class file for `java.lang.Object`. A module reader may treat
>   directories in the module content as resources (whether it does or not is
>   module reader specific). Where the module content contains a directory
>   that can be located as a resource then its name ends with a slash (`'/'`). The directory can also be located with a name that drops the trailing slash.

Do keep in mind though, that the docs also specify :

> A ModuleReader is open upon creation and is closed by invoking the
>   [`close`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleReader.html#close--)
>   method. Failure to close a module reader may result in a resource
>   leak. The [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement provides a useful construct to
>   ensure that module readers are closed.

---

One  way to get the `Module` from the resources would be to access it using the [`Class#getModule`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getModule--) as:

```
Module module = com.foo.bar.YourClass.class.getModule();
```

---

***Edit***: I've learned with time a better way to use the `ModuleFinder` to access a `Module` as suggested by [@Alan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46180598/1746118) as well could possibly be :

```
ModuleFinder finder = ModuleFinder.of(path);
ModuleLayer parent = ModuleLayer.boot();
Configuration configuration = parent.configuration().resolve(finder, ModuleFinder.of(), Set.of("curious")); // 'curious' being the name of the module
ClassLoader systemClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
ModuleLayer layer = parent.defineModulesWithOneLoader(configuration, systemClassLoader);

Module m = layer.findModule("curious").orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 3):

The classes in java.lang.module are more model world. Look at `java.lang.module.Configuration` and also `java.lang.ModuleLayer` to see how to create a configuration and instantiate it in the Java virtual machine as a layer of modules. There is a code fragment in the `ModuleLayer` javadoc that might get you going, just be warned that this is an advanced topic and best to master the basics first.