# How to get list of all modules programmatically in Java 9?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

How can I get list of all modules in current JVM instance via Java code? Is it possible? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
ModuleLayer.boot().modules().stream()
                .map(Module::getName)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: This is only true if there boot layer is the only layer. If modules are loaded by different class loaders, this list will be incomplete.

Comment: Sure, but the code fragment will get the person asking the question started. There are of course APIs for tools and debuggers to enumerate all modules in the VM, including unnamed modules, but that is way beyond what I suspect the question is about.

Comment: I disagree, Alan Bateman -- this answer is incomplete. As you hint in your comment, this does not even return unnamed modules or automatic modules, which are and will continue to be very common during the early years of Java 9.

Comment: Luke - automatic modules are named modules. If there are any automatic modules in the boot layer then they will be included.

Comment: Can I somehow get the packages of each of these modules?

Comment: Yes, of course, look at ModuleReader.

Answer (score 7):

Using a jar or directory of modules as an input for your application, you can possibly use a [`ModuleFinder`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleFinder.html) to start off with and further making use of the **[`findAll`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleFinder.html#findAll--)** to find *the set of all module references that this finder can locate.*

```
Path dir1, dir2, dir3;
ModuleFinder finder = ModuleFinder.of(dir1, dir2, dir3);
Set<ModuleReference> moduleReferences = finder.findAll();
```

---

This is easily possible with the command line option to list the modules as:

```
java -p <jarfile> --list-modules
```

which should be sufficient though, if you do not want to intentionally get into [tweaking things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180116/how-to-get-a-module-object-from-a-modulereference) with the [`ModuleLayer`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/ModuleLayer.html) and the [`Configuration`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/module/Configuration.html) of the **[`java.lang.module`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/module/package-summary.html)** as pointed out precisely by [@Alan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46268233/1746118).